# Is there any function f which is only differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and such that $f^{-1} = f'$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function

Is there any function f which is only differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and such that $f^{-1} = f'$?

I thinks  there exists no such function. I thought about  constant, exponential, trigonometric function, etc., but I didn't find any function which is only    differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and such that $f^{-1} = f'$.

Is it true?

Comment: Are you thinking about $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, of $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is bijective ? Or only that $f$ is injective ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is at least one such function. Let us start by assuming that $f(x)=kx^\alpha$, for some $k,\alpha>0$. Then $f'(x)=k\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$ and $f^{-1}(x)=k^{-\frac1\alpha}x^\frac1\alpha$. So, when do you have$$\bigl(\forall x\in(0,+\infty)\bigr):k\alpha x^{\alpha-1}=k^{-\frac1\alpha}x^\frac1\alpha?$$We must have $\alpha-1=\frac1\alpha$, which means that $\alpha=\varphi$ (the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)). And then $k$ must be such that $k^{-\frac1\varphi}=k\varphi$, wich is equivalent to $k^{-\frac1\varphi-1}=\varphi$. Numerically, $k\approx0.7427$.

If you allow $\alpha$ to be negative, the same approach leads to another solution, of the form $x\mapsto kx^{-\frac1\varphi}.$